# No data found Exception

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc

I was working on jdbc odbc connection using servlets.But am getting java.sql.SQLException: No data found.What can be the reason.?Please help.I am looking for my mistake since a day but not able to get it till yet.

```
Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null,ps1=null,ps2=null;
ResultSet rs=null,rs1=null;


con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SharedCryptography", "fyp", "fyp");
ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tbGroup values ('G0',?,?,?,'Y')");
ps2=con.prepareStatement("insert into tbGroupAdmin values ('U0',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Here String n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8 are strings obtained from html form

```
String sql1 = "SELECT GNAME,OEMAIL FROM tbGroup where GNAME = '"+n1+"' and OEMAIL = '"+n3+"'" ;          
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
rs=ps1.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
  out.println("THIS GROUP WITH SAME ID EXISTS");  
}
else{
    ps.setString(1,n1);
    ps.setString(2,n3);
    ps.setString(3,n5);
    ps.execute();
    out.println("inserted");
    ResultSet rs2=null;

    String sql2="SELECT G_ID FROM tbGroup where GNAME like '"+n1+"' and OEMAIL like '"+n3+"'";
    PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    rs2=ps3.executeQuery();

    rs2.next();
    String mypassword="password";
    ps2.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));
    ps2.setString(2,n2);
    ps2.setString(3,mypassword);
    ps2.setString(4,n6);
    ps2.setString(5,n7); 
    ps2.setString(6,n3);
    ps2.setString(7,n4);
    ps2.setInt(8,Integer.parseInt(n8));
    ps2.execute();

}
```

My database has two tables :

TABLE 1 : tbGroup

```
G_ID    VARCHAR2(10)    
GNAME   VARCHAR2(20)        
OEMAIL  VARCHAR2(50)        
Agenda  VARCHAR2(50)    
Status  CHAR(5)
```

Table 2 : tbGroupAdmin

```
GADMIN_ID           VARCHAR2(5) 
GA_GROUPID          VARCHAR2(5) 
GA_NAME         VARCHAR2(20)
GA_PASSWORD         VARCHAR2(20)    
GA_FNAME            VARCHAR2(20)    
LastName            VARCHAR2(20)    
GA_EmailId          VARCHAR2(50)    
GA_ContactNumber    VARCHAR2(20)    
GA_Age          NUMBER
```

Comment: You've posted 90 lines of code, but given no indication of *where* the exception is thrown. Ideally, you should work to reduce this as far as possible so that the code you post *just* contains what's required to reproduce the issue. (Do you need *all* those queries and non-queries in order to reproduce the issue?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Before executing ps2 I printed all the values i used to set ps2.They are printed right.But i dont know whats wrong going on after that

Comment: That hasn't really answered my question. It *suggests* that it's `ps2.execute()` that's throwing the exception, but you should be clearer about that - and remove anything unnecessary from your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I posted the whole code so that their is not problem in explaining it.And yeah i too agree that their is problem woth ps2.execute().But whats the problem am not getting it

Comment: Posting too much code is nearly as bad as not posting enough code. It's very important to try to cut examples down as far as you can. (The broken indentation doesn't help, either.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried to reduce the code now.Hope it helps

Comment: Well you could still do a lot more... have you reproduced this *without* the first query at all? Just hard-code some data which makes sense. And the indentation is still broken.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is the best i could do.Hope this will help you detect my problem

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like "No, I haven't tried it without the first query" *Have* you actually tried to reproduce it with just the one query (`insert into tbGroupAdmin ...`)?

Comment: (As an aside, I hadn't spotted it before but your `sql1` is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. *Always* use parameterized SQL!

Comment: Can you please provide StackTrace...?

Comment: @JonSkeet I will modify it,No problem.But why this exception?Any reason for it?

Comment: I don't know yet - the more you can pin it down, the more likely we are to discover the reason. That's my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complete guess but why are you doing this?

```
if(rs.next()){
  out.println("THIS GROUP WITH SAME ID EXISTS");  
}
```

As it will return true if it has `row`. **So from this I came to know that you want to check whether there is a row with this ID?**

What you are doing above is

```
String sql1 = "SELECT GNAME,OEMAIL FROM tbGroup where GNAME = '"+n1+"' and OEMAIL = '"+n3+"'";
```

As you need to do is

```
select G_ID from tbGroup where GNAME = '"+n1+"' and OEMAIL = '"+n3+"'";
```

*So that you can determine same  G_ID exist or not.*

As I think you misplaced *sql1* and *sql2*

Moreover in your code you are setting

```
ps2.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));//this string may have size>5 as G_ID has size 10
```

while G_ADMINID has size `VARCHAR2(5)`

*Sorry if I went wrong.*

Comment: actually code runs fine before ps2 executes.I printed all rs2.getString(1),n1,n2,n3 and all before assigning it to db they are absolutly fine